# Зачем нужен класс Request? JavaScript. Если есть XMLHTTPRequest и Fetch API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Смотрю туториал и автор не объяснил, зачем делает так:

```
let request = new Request(url);
fetch(request);
```

Зачем он создал экземпляр от Request? Если можно было через XMLHTTP, или просто бы он мог пихнуть url в fetch. Я знаю, что вы без полного кода не поймёте.
Вот ссылка: https://jsfiddle.net/v05e76zt/
Объясните разницу пожалуйста между new Request, new XMLHTTPRequest. Мне кажется второй легче. И зачем пихать request в fetch. Туда ведь вроде url достаточно пихнуть.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: кроме GET запросов, есть ещё запросы PUT, PATCH, DELETE, UPDATE, POST и там иногда нужно отправлять в header'ах какие-то данные, а также в теле запроса. с помощью Request можно это всё просто описать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постараюсь ответить покороче.

Давайте разберемся для начала. Зачем нужен fetch если есть XMLHttpRequest?

1. fetch API современный. А [точнее](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/the-fetch-api-2c962591f5c#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Google%20Developers%20Documentation,than%20with%20the%20older%20XMLHttpRequest%20.&text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20Fetch,Promises%2C%20hence%20avoiding%20callback%20hell.)

> Fetch is a new native JavaScript API, supported by most browsers
> today. Fetch allows you to make network requests similar to
> XMLHttpRequest. According to Google Developers Documentation Fetch
> makes it easier to make asynchronous requests and handle responses
> better than with the older XMLHttpRequest. It is an improvement over
> the XMLHttpRequest API. The main difference between Fetch and
> XMLHttpRequest is that the Fetch API uses Promises, hence avoiding
> callback hell.

Все почти тоже самое, а главное fetch api это про промисы. А промисы это решение против коллбек хела.

2. Так зачем [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)? А он часть fetch API.

> The Request interface of the Fetch API represents a resource request.